# Adding a callout/speech bubble to the User annotation of a MapView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mapbox

Right now my app display a customUserAnnotationView with a custom image where the user annotation is (you can see this in ViewController.swift). I have also created a custom UIView that I want to use as an annotation just above the user annotation (the code and image for it are under SpeechBubble.swift).

I want to combine these two objects so that I can show the CustomUserAnnotationView with the Custom UIView(SpeechBubble.swift) placed in an annotation above.

My attempts at making a frankenstein program [from](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/default-callout/) [multiple](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/marker/) [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/custom-callout/) [tutorials](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/user-location-annotation/) have not worked out for me. I only want to place the custom annotation class I created above the image, and maybe add a small triangle to make it look like a speech bubble.

---

ViewController.swift

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Enable heading tracking mode so that the arrow will appear.
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

        // Enable the permanent heading indicator, which will appear when the tracking mode is not `.followWithHeading`.
        mapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator = true

        view.addSubview(mapView)

        let idea =  UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
        idea.text = "Hello There"
        idea.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        let sb = SpeechBubble(coord: mapView.targetCoordinate, idea: idea)
        mapView.addSubview(sb)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // Substitute our custom view for the user location annotation. This custom view is defined below.
        if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
            return Avatar()
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Optional: tap the user location annotation to toggle heading tracking mode.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        if mapView.userTrackingMode != .followWithHeading {
            mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
        } else {
            mapView.resetNorth()
        }

        // We're borrowing this method as a gesture recognizer, so reset selection state.
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
    }
}
```

[image]

---

SpeechBubble.swift

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class SpeechBubble: UIView, MGLMapViewDelegate{

    //var sbView: UIView

    init(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, idea: UITextView) {

        let width = CGFloat(180)
        let height = UITextField.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height + 32
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(coord.latitude), y: CGFloat(coord.longitude), width: width, height: height))

        self.addSubview(idea)
        self.addSubview(buttonsView());
        self.addSubview(upvoteView());
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func upvoteView() -> UIView {
        let uView = UIView()

        let vCnt = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        vCnt.center = CGPoint(x: 10.5, y: 32)
        vCnt.textAlignment = .center
        vCnt.text = "0"

        let uButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
        uButton.frame = CGRect(x: vCnt.frame.size.width + 5, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32);
        let uImage = UIImage (named: "Upvote")
        uButton.setImage(uImage, for: .normal)

        uView.frame.size.width = vCnt.frame.size.width + uButton.frame.size.width + 5
        uView.frame.size.height = max(vCnt.frame.size.height, uButton.frame.size.height)

        uView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: self.frame.size.height - uView.frame.size.height,
            width: uView.frame.size.width,
            height: uView.frame.size.height );
        uView.addSubview(vCnt)
        uView.addSubview(uButton)
        return uView
    }

    func buttonsView() -> UIView {
        let bView = UIView()

        let jButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
        rButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 32);
        let rImage = UIImage (named: "Rocket")
        rButton.setImage(rImage, for: .normal)

        let pButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
        pButton.frame = CGRect(x: jButton.frame.size.width + 5, y: 0, width: 31, height: 36);
        let pImage = UIImage (named: "Profile")
        pButton.setImage(pImage, for: .normal)

        bView.frame.size.width = rButton.frame.size.width + pButton.frame.size.width + 5
        bView.frame.size.height = max(rButton.frame.size.height, pButton.frame.size.height)

        bView.frame = CGRect(
            x: self.frame.size.width - bView.frame.size.width,
            y: self.frame.size.height - bView.frame.size.height,
            width: bView.frame.size.width,
            height: bView.frame.size.height );
        bView.addSubview(rButton)
        bView.addSubview(pButton)
        return bView
    }

}
```

[image]

---

Avatar.swift

```
import Mapbox

class Avatar: MGLUserLocationAnnotationView {
    let size: CGFloat = 48
    var arrow: CALayer!
    //var arrow: CAShapeLayer!

    // -update is a method inherited from MGLUserLocationAnnotationView. It updates the appearance of the user location annotation when needed. This can be called many times a second, so be careful to keep it lightweight.
    override func update() {
        if frame.isNull {
            frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
            return setNeedsLayout()
        }

        // Check whether we have the user’s location yet.
        if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(userLocation!.coordinate) {
            setupLayers()
            updateHeading()
        }
    }

    private func updateHeading() {
        // Show the heading arrow, if the heading of the user is available.
        if let heading = userLocation!.heading?.trueHeading {
            arrow.isHidden = false

            // Get the difference between the map’s current direction and the user’s heading, then convert it from degrees to radians.
            let rotation: CGFloat = -MGLRadiansFromDegrees(mapView!.direction - heading)

            // If the difference would be perceptible, rotate the arrow.
            if abs(rotation) > 0.01 {
                // Disable implicit animations of this rotation, which reduces lag between changes.
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
                arrow.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: rotation))
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        } else {
            arrow.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    private func setupLayers() {
        // This dot forms the base of the annotation.
        if arrow == nil {
            arrow = CALayer()
            let myImage = UIImage(named: "will_smith")?.cgImage
            arrow.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size)
            arrow.contents = myImage
            layer.addSublayer(arrow)
        }

    }

    // Calculate the vector path for an arrow, for use in a shape layer.
    private func arrowPath() -> CGPath {
        let max: CGFloat = size / 2
        let pad: CGFloat = 3

        let top =    CGPoint(x: max * 0.5, y: 0)
        let left =   CGPoint(x: 0 + pad,   y: max - pad)
        let right =  CGPoint(x: max - pad, y: max - pad)
        let center = CGPoint(x: max * 0.5, y: max * 0.6)

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: top)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: left)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: center)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: right)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: top)
        bezierPath.close()

        return bezierPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

---

---

**UPDATE**
I tried to create a Frankenstein program of the Answer and my code and am receiving the following the error `Property 'self.representedObject' not initialized at super.init call` within SpeechBubble.swift. I also move all my old code from speechBubble.swift into insideSpeechBubble.swift

***Updated SpeechBubble.swift***

```
    import UIKit
    import Mapbox

    class SpeechBubble: UIView, MGLCalloutView {

        // Your IBOutlets //

        var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
        var annotationPoint: CGPoint
        // Required views but unused for this implementation.
        lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView()
        lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView()
        var contentView: MGLMapView
        weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

        // MARK: - init methods

        required init(annotation: MGLAnnotation, frame: CGRect, annotationPoint: CGPoint) {
            let idea =  UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
            idea.text = "Hello There"
            idea.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            self.representedObject = annotation
            self.annotationPoint = annotationPoint
            contentView = InsideSpeechBubble(coord: annotationPoint, idea: idea )
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }

        private func commonInit() {
            Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SpeechBubble", owner: self, options: nil)
            addSubview(contentView as UIView)
            contentView.frame = self.bounds

            // Do your initialisation //
        }

        // MARK: - MGLCalloutView methods

        func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
            // Present the custom callout slightly above the annotation's view. Initially invisble.
            self.center = annotationPoint.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height - 20.0))

            // I have logic here for setting the correct image and button states //
        }

        func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
            removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

---

***Updated ViewController.swift***

```
import Mapbox


class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    //let point = MGLPointAnnotation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Enable heading tracking mode so that the arrow will appear.
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

        // Enable the permanent heading indicator, which will appear when the tracking mode is not `.followWithHeading`.
        mapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator = true

        view.addSubview(mapView)

        let HighDea =  UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
        HighDea.text = "Hello There"
        HighDea.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        //let sb = SpeechBubble()
        //mapView.addSubview(sb)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // Substitute our custom view for the user location annotation. This custom view is defined below.
        if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
            return Avatar()
        }
        return nil
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {
        // Do your annotation-specific preparation here //

        // I get the correct size from my xib file.
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 261.0, height: 168.0))
        // Get the annotation's location in the view's coordinate system.
        let annotationPoint = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: nil)

        let customCalloutView = SpeechBubble(annotation: annotation, frame: viewFrame, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)

        return customCalloutView
    }

//    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // This example is only concerned with point annotations.
//        guard annotation is MGLPointAnnotation else {
//            return nil
//        }

        // Use the point annotation’s longitude value (as a string) as the reuse identifier for its view.
//        let reuseIdentifier = "\(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"

        // For better performance, always try to reuse existing annotations.
//        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // If there’s no reusable annotation view available, initialize a new one.
//        if annotationView == nil {
//            annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
//            annotationView!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

            // Set the annotation view’s background color to a value determined by its longitude.
  //          let hue = CGFloat(annotation.coordinate.longitude) / 100
  //          annotationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
  //      }

  //      return annotationView
  //  }

    // Optional: tap the user location annotation to toggle heading tracking mode.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        if mapView.userTrackingMode != .followWithHeading {
            mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
        } else {
            mapView.resetNorth()
        }

        // We're borrowing this method as a gesture recognizer, so reset selection state.
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I implemented a custom callout for my Mapbox annotations I used a xib file to design the actual callout. I find that it gives me a lot more instant feedback than than trying to conjure the UI from code (but obviously do whatever your preference is).

[image]

Which gives me something like the following.

[image]

Using a UIImage for the background allows me to achieve any shape I choose. Here I use transparency around the white to give me the circular elements and the bottom triangle you mention in your question.

The Swift file for this UIView (your SpeechBubble) needs to conform to the `MGLCalloutView` protocol not `MGLMapViewDelegate` as you have it currently. Your `ViewController` is the `MGLMapViewDelegate`, not your custom callout. Pair the xib file and the Swift file in the usual way in Identity Inspector in IB. So would be something like this:

```
    import UIKit
    import Mapbox

    class SpeechBubble: UIView, MGLCalloutView {

    // Your IBOutlets //
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView! // The custom callout's view.

    var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
    var annotationPoint: CGPoint
    // Required views but unused for this implementation.
    lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView()
    lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView()

    weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

    // MARK: - init methods

    required init(annotation: YourAnnotation, frame: CGRect, annotationPoint: CGPoint) {
        self.representedObject = annotation
        self.annotationPoint = annotationPoint

        super.init(frame: frame)

        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SpeechBubble", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds

        // Do your initialisation //
    }

    // MARK: - MGLCalloutView methods

    func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        // Present the custom callout slightly above the annotation's view. Initially invisble.
        self.center = annotationPoint.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height - 20.0))

        // I have logic here for setting the correct image and button states //
    }

    func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Then you just seem to be missing the `MGLMapViewDelegate` method to actually return your `SpeechBubble` view when requested. It should be in your `ViewController` file.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {
        // Do your annotation-specific preparation here //

        // I get the correct size from my xib file.
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 261.0, height: 168.0))
        // Get the annotation's location in the view's coordinate system.
        let annotationPoint = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: nil)
        let customCalloutView = SpeechBubble(annotation: YourAnnotation, frame: viewFrame, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)

        return customCalloutView
    }
```

Hopefully this will get you closer to achieving what you're trying to do. BTW this version of your question is miles ahead of the first one.

EDIT +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

It's going to be almost impossible to work this through without sight of your project so I have put together a bare bones implementation. It is based on the Mapbox example here: [Mapbox Custom Callout](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/custom-callout/) which for some reason doesn't show how to actually supply the callout view. I've also extended it to allow for a custom annotation image. If you can get this working you should be able to move the relevant parts into your own project.

I strongly recommend that if you try to implement the stuff below that you do it in a fresh project.

The view controller.

```
    import Mapbox

    class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: MGLStyle.lightStyleURL)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.tintColor = .darkGray
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Set the map view‘s delegate property.
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Initialize and add the marker annotation.
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        let marker = MyAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, title: "Bingo", subtitle: "Bongo")

        // Add marker to the map.
        mapView.addAnnotation(marker)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLCalloutView? {
        // Instantiate and return our custom callout view.
        let annotationPoint = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: nil)
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 250.0, height: 178.0))
        return CustomCalloutView(representedObject: annotation, frame: viewFrame, annotationPoint: annotationPoint)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "myAnnotationView") {
            return annotationView
        } else {
            let annotationView = MyAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotationView", size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45), annotation: annotation)
            return annotationView
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        // Optionally handle taps on the callout.
        print("Tapped the callout for: \(annotation)")

        // Hide the callout.
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

CustomCalloutView.swift

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class CustomCalloutView: UIView, MGLCalloutView {

@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

weak var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
var annotationPoint: CGPoint
// Required views but unused for this implementation.
lazy var leftAccessoryView = UIView()
lazy var rightAccessoryView = UIView()

required init(representedObject: MGLAnnotation, frame: CGRect, annotationPoint: CGPoint) {
    self.representedObject = representedObject
    self.annotationPoint = annotationPoint

    super.init(frame: frame)

    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    self.representedObject = MyAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate, title: "", subtitle: "")
    self.annotationPoint = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
}

func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedRect: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
    // Present the custom callout slightly above the annotation's view. Initially invisble.
    self.center = annotationPoint.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: -120.0))

    view.addSubview(self)
}

func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
    removeFromSuperview()
}
```

}

This is associated/identified with a xib file. It just contains a simple image shape for now. I had to (re)introduce the contentView IBOutlet as I was having trouble loading things from the Bundle and adding it to self in commonInit() made everything happy.

[image]

The custom annotation class.

```
    import UIKit
    import Mapbox

    // MGLAnnotation protocol reimplementation
    class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

    // As a reimplementation of the MGLAnnotation protocol, we have to add mutable coordinate and (sub)title properties ourselves.
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    // Custom properties that we will use to customize the annotation.
    var image: UIImage?
    var reuseIdentifier: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle

        self.reuseIdentifier = "myAnnotation"
    }
}
```

The MGLAnnotationView subclass.

```
    import UIKit
    import Mapbox

    class MyAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {

    init(reuseIdentifier: String, size: CGSize, annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // This property prevents the annotation from changing size when the map is tilted.
        scalesWithViewingDistance = false

        // Begin setting up the view.
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        var image = UIImage()
        if annotation is MyAnnotation {
            image = UIImage(named: "frog")!
        }

        imageView.image = image
        addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[image]

Naturally there is a lot of hard coded numbers and the requirement for an image called frog but you can change all of that and improve it as you wish. The CustomCalloutView.swift and CustomCalloutView.xib need to be linked in the usual way in the identity inspector, etc.

Comment: My main concern is that I want to use my callout as a class and not as a single view. For the end product, I'm going to have multiple users on the map, who each may or may not have one these callouts. I also want to customize the text within the view per person. Is this type of thing possible using an xib file created in storyboard?

I also don't understand the point of putting `@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!` inside the speech bubble class. Is it adding something extra into the view? Thank you

Comment: And the variable 'YourAnnotation'. Is that just whatever image I decide to put in there? Like my Will Smith image in this case?

Comment: The callout is a separate object from the annotation. The annotation has a title, subtitle and coordinate and you are supplying an image too. In this specific case you're supplying an image of Will Smith but the image isn't your annotation, it is just its image. When you tap on one of your annotations the delegate method mapView-annotationcanShowCallout is called. You provide the logic in there as to whether that annotation can show a callout or not.

Comment: If you look at the answer you'll see that the callout shows a title and a coordinate. All of my callouts show information specific to the particular annotation that was tapped. It's standard behaviour. The xib isn't a class but when you combine it with the Swift file that is a subclass of UIView it becomes a class. So it isn't just a view it is a fully reusable class in the normal way. Where I indicated you would put your IBOutlets refers to the labels, etc that you fill with the appropriate data. The contentView is just left over fro. one of my own implementations.

Comment: I tried implementing the differences into my code but for some reasong I'm not understanding some stuff, like the fact that my will smith head is an annotationView and not just an annotation, so I'm having trouble trying to reference it, and I don't know how to deal with the init that has a decoder. I'll try making the storyboard for my view and implementing like how you said

Comment: When I do it exactly like how you said I get `Property 'self.representedObject' not initialized at super.init call` for the line `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`

Comment: I replace the init?(coder: aDecoder) fucntion with required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       ` fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } ` and the code runs, but I receive thread1:signal SIGABRT when I click on the icon

Comment: Also, I want the text from the view to always be there( until it's about 6 hours old) and for the view to expand to show the buttons when you click on it

Comment: But If it's either it's all there or it isn't, I would like for it to just be there

Comment: I think the problem is the decoder needs to be there, but I don't know how to initialize the objects in the class

Comment: I tried to fix the decoder by initializing some values as                 `representedObject = [] as! MGLAnnotation
        annotationPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` but I'm still get the same  Thread 1: Signal  sigabrt in my AppDelegate. How come it's working for you?

Comment: Do you have a class for your annotation? In super.init(coder: aDecoder) try setting representedObject = YourAnnotation(whatever initialisation variables you have here). You should be able to use dummy values here since the coder init is required in Swift but not actually ever called here.

Comment: No, I just have an that class `avatar` which is an mglannotationview

Comment: I used forced unwrapping on the representedobject and annotationview with `!` . Is that good enough?

I still receive the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in my AppDelegate method though

Comment: I just realized where you put // Do your annotation-specific preparation here // I didn't do anything. I don't know what to do there.
I have that avatar class that creates an annotationView

Comment: I fixed the previous error by recreating my project, something was wrong with my main.storyboard. Now I'm receiving `[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C25.1:2][0x108803880] get output frames failed, state 8196` and `finished with error - code: -999`. Which apparently the 999 error doesn't say a lot because it just says that another error occured during the correction of the original error or something.

Comment: I don't know what to put in for the annotation. I don't understand how this function gets called? I see know calls to it anywhere else.

Comment: @Jacob - I've added a complete new skeleton to the bottom of my previous answer. Please try to implement that and if you can get it working at least you have a platform to move forward from.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use `self.center = annotationPoint.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: -120.0))` instead of just something like `self.center = CGPoint(x: annotationPoint.x, y: annotationPoint.y)`. I've noticed when I use the latter the x coordinate of the callout is to the left, but I don't know how to explain it?

Comment: The off center problem is happening for either method.